# Can I prevent background sync of firestore from old version client?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, offlineapps

I want to control background sync of google-firebase's **firestore** db with persistance mode (`PersistenceEnabled` to `true`).

I'm afraid the old version client, works offline and don't know the app's version-up (with some destructive updates), may upload local-data to server when change to online.
In this case, I want to check current app versions and allow/not allow before sync.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Data in the cache is only updated when you attach a listener/observer to it. There is no automatic synchronization happening for the data in the offline cache.

This means that you can add a version check to your application startup code, before you attach any observers. Simply store a `database-version` field in a global document, and check against that upon application startup. If the version is greater than what the app was made to handle, show an upgrade prompt.

Comment: Thanks your apply but,, if app startup with offline, the check is difficult, isn't it?
Or `global document` means something important point?

Comment: Nope, there's no magic meaning to "global document". It's just a document that you use to store a variable such as this.

Comment: But I'd recommend not relying on the app version for write validation. Instead just create security rules that validate the data structure. That way, the server will always validate against the latest rules. If writes from old clients violate those rules, they'll get rejected. So: use a version number to ensure your app code can handle the data, use security rules to ensure your apps write validate (and to reject writes from old apps that write data that is no longer up to snuff).

Comment: I knows about rules, but `auth` information haven't version info, isn't it?
In that case, What should I do?
I think about rules like below:
`match /documents/wantToPrevent { allow read, write: if request.resource.data.current_version >= X.X; }`
but, this strategy needs `current_version` data-field for all document.
This is ugly, so I want to avoid if possible.